# How to fetch record from two table in one query

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table

1. `rental_detail` -> [ `id`, `Building`, `Floor`, `Flate_no`, `Name`,`doj`]

`rental_detail` Stores the information of the person.
this is `rental_detail`

`|id|name|building|Floor|Flate_no|doj
 |1 |aana|   C    | 1st |c-101  |06-12-2015`

And in

2. `Monthly_rent` -> [ `id`, `Building`, `Floor`, `Flate_no`, `date` ] Stores the  details of per month rent pay by the person

this is `month_rent`

`|id|building|Floor|Flate_no|date     |rent|
 |1 |   C    | 1st |c-101  |02-01-2016|2000
 |2 |   C    | 1st |c-101  |03-02-2016|2000
 |1 |   C    | 1st |c-101  |06-12-2015|2000`

I need the Max date from `Monthly_rent` and all information about person from `rental_detail` where building is c, floor is 1st and flate is c-101

**I tried this query:**

```
select *,max(mr.date) as m 
from monthly_rent mr 
Inner join rental_details rd 
   on rd.building='C' and rd.floor = '1st' And rd.flate_no='C-101
```

I need this

`|1|aana|C|1st|c-101|03-02-2016|`

aana pay last rent at 03-02-2016

Comment: what you get output ??

Comment: max date from monthlyrent where Building is c , floor is 1st and flate is c-101

Comment: Don't do unnecessary JOIN, when you have simple query. Just match unique id related with both the table.

Comment: add group by mr.id at the bottom

Comment: its can't work without join @user4499992

Comment: I think if you use combination of union and join you can achieve what you required. But it will depend on structure and data of your tables. So , Please provide the structure of your tables with some dummy data.

Comment: How can you perform join if there is no foreign key in either of the table?

Comment: in booth table building,floor,flate_no are same

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT rd .*,mr.date AS mr_date  
FROM rental_details rd 
LEFT JOIN monthly_rent mr 
ON rd.date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM monthly_rent WHERE building='C' )
WHERE rd.building='C' AND rd.floor = '1st' AND rd.flate_no='C-101'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select *, max(mr.date) as m 
from monthly_rent mr, rental_details rd
where mr.id = rd.id 
and rd.building='C' 
and rd.floor = '1st' 
and rd.flate_no='C-101'
```

this should work....

Comment: its take max date from rentat_detail table

Comment: yes! because you are asking for it. change it to rd.date

Comment: its display common date from both table

Comment: why would it take common date when you are specifying which table you are taking the date from?

what are you using mySQL?

Comment: yes i using mysql, yes i spcifice but it take commom date

Comment: can you give me SQL script for both the table? I will try it here

Comment: try max(DATE(mr.date))

Comment: ya sure i will send u

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103709/discussion-between-aanal-shah-and-tanvir-alam).

Comment: you kept Date as Varchar, that is why Max is not working change it to DATE or DATETIME

Comment: Or if you don't want to change your table structure then try 
MAX(STR_TO_DATE('mr.date','YOUR-DATE-FORMAT'))
Date format is m-d-Y then use %m-%d-%Y

Answer (score 0):

try like this, it should help ..

```
select rd.*,max(mr.date) as m 
from monthly_rent as mr 
LEFT join rental_details as rd ON mr.building = rd.building
WHERE rd.floor = '1st' and rd.flate_no='C-101'
```